# Appmaker: Home Page "AppStart" upon user role

Tags: google-app-maker

I want the Admin's start page to be the Admin Console and for the user another page - "MyTickets". The default start page for the app is MyTickets but I don't want the Admin to see this as the start page nor be able to navigate to it.

I found in the Appmaker's templates "Training hub" some code for the Appstart depending on the user role, as I want; However, when I implemented it, I get this error in the console

[image]

The page keeps loading while in the template it works normally.
Here is the code I inserted in my app in client script:

```
/**
 * Determines whether the user has specified role.
 * @param {string} roleName - name of the role to check.
 * @return {boolean} true if user has the role.
 */
function hasRole(roleName) {
  return (app.user.roles.indexOf(roleName) > -1);
}


/**
 * Determines whether the user is admin.
 * @return {boolean} true if user is an admin.
 */
function isAdmin() {
  return hasRole('Admins');
}

/**
 * Gets start page depends on current user's roles.
 * @return {Page} start page to be shown to user.
 */
function getUserStartPage() {
  var result = app.pages.MyTickets;
  var userRoles = app.user.roles;

  if (isAdmin()) {
    result = app.pages.Admin_console;
  }
  return result;
}


/**
 * Overrides start page if loading is not specified.
 * @param {string} currentPageName - name of current page to be loaded.
 * @return {Page} start page to be shown to user.
 */
function overrideStartPage(currentPageName) {
  if (currentPageName) {
    return;
  }

  var startPage = getUserStartPage();
  gotoPage(startPage);
}


/**
 * Handles Application Start event.
 * Loads Application Settings and then loads the app.
 * @param {AppLoader} loader - instance of application loader.
 */
function onAppStart(loader) {
  loader.suspendLoad();
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    app.datasources.AppSettings.load({
      success: function() {
        overrideStartPage(location.hash);
        loader.resumeLoad();
      },
      failure: function() {
        overrideStartPage(location.hash);
        loader.resumeLoad();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And in the  app's settings, the startup script is:

```
 onAppStart(loader);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to dig a bit more into javascript or into the app maker documentation. The solution is very easy but since you are copying and pasting the source code without understanding what is happening, you are having difficulties resolving this matter. Here is the code you need to use:

```
loader.suspendLoad();
if(app.user.role.Admins){
  app.showPage(app.pages.Admin_console);
} else {
  app.showPage(app.pages.MyTickets);
}
loader.resumeLoad();
```

**Note Bene:** The above code should be used exactly as it is inside the **App Settings - App startup script**

References: https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#App

Comment: Thanks alot @Morfinismo
It worked. I agreed that I should dig more into javascript.